# Integral Form of Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind

Tags: special-functions

Why can't Mathematica integrate

```
r = Integrate[Exp[-x Cosh[t]], {t, 0, Infinity}];
r = Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Simplify[r]];
Together[r]
```

From Wikipedia, it should be $K_0(x)$, the modified Bessel function of the second kind for $\alpha =0$, since$$K_\alpha(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-x\cosh t) \cosh(\alpha t) \,dt.$$ And there is definitely a `BesselK` function in Mathematica. It seems like a similar problem to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19597/reproducing-the-integral-definition-of-the-modified-bessel-function).

Comment: It has been like that for a while; I'm not sure why. In any case, try making the substitution $u=\cosh t$ before using `Integrate[]`.

Comment: To elaborate on the comment by @J.M., `Integrate[Exp[-x u]/Sqrt[u^2 - 1], {u, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x > 0]` gives the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.